# PHP Get name of child class in static function

Tags: php, class

Is something like this possible?

```
<?
class A
{
   public static function fun()
   {
      var_dump(get_class(child)); //bool(false) //should return B
   }
}
class B extends A
{
   public static function fun()
   {
      parent::fun();
   }
}

B::fun();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
class B extends A
{
   public static function fun()
   {
      parent::fun();
   }
}
class A
{
   public static function fun()
   {
      var_dump(get_called_class());
   }
}

B::fun();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php

Answer (score 2):

As of PHP 5.3, there is [`get_called_class()`](http://php.net/get_called_class) for this purpose:

```
echo get_called_class(); // yields "B"
```